# Uploading A file via a form

Tags: php, forms, upload, permissions

I have written a form which has 3 text inputs and one file input.
This form posts to a PHP script, which saves the file, as well as performing some other business logic. The program worked well in my localhost, and even on my server.

The program is now embedded in a Facebook application, where it still works- but the uploaded files were not saving, initally; So I changed the uploads directory permissions to 777 (a broad stroke, I know). Now the uploaded files are being saved as a string of numbers "13474022561" with no extension.

Can anyone tell me why? Or how to fix this?

snippet of source code below:

```
  if($_FILES['resume']['type']!='')
  {
        $target_path = "resumes/";

        $target_path = $target_path .time().basename( $_FILES['resume']['name']!="");
        if($_FILES['resume']['type']=="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" || $_FILES['resume']['type']=="application/pdf")
        {
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) 
            {
                echo "success";
            }
            else
                echo "failure";
        }
        else 
        {
                echo "<center>Resume must be MS DOC or PDF <br/>";                    
                exit;
        }
  }
```

Comment: Do you want to add the code?

Comment: my research shows people want to see the code

Comment: Please post your code so that we can help you.

Comment: Seems that you were looking for [**very specific StackExchange site**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/39378/alchemy-mysticism-and-magic) , but unfortunately it hasn't been approved yet.

Comment: Yay! The code is posted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code:

```
$target_path = $target_path .time().basename( $_FILES['resume']['name']!="");
```

Should be:

```
$target_path = $target_path . time() . basename( $_FILES['resume']['name']);
```

Your current code is evaluated like this:

```
$target_path = 'resumes/' . time() . basename(true);
```

Which is probably not what you want.

Comment: just needed fresh eyes. Thanks Shaquin.